# Send function to new thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

On Android when I am mapping an address on a Mapview I have to wait for that action to return and then my user is given control back so I was wondering how can I send that function of to another thread?

```
mapLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mapCurrentAddress(); //Send this function to new thread
            }
        });
```

How can this be done? And how will the new thread respond when it's done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android provides the AsyncTask class to do that. Read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Can AsyncTask be implemented as an inner class?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an AsyncTask to do this work in the background. Check this [example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


    public void onClick(View v) {

p_dialog = ProgressDialog.show((activity_name).this, "", "Loading Image...");

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    function();
                }
            }).start();


    }
```